# How to solve for $A$ in $A - BAB^T = CC^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Considering an unknown real symmetric matrix $A$, and two known matrix $B$ and $C$.

If we have the equation: 
$$
A - BAB^T = CC^T
$$

Can we get an analytical solution of A?

Comment: you multiply with inverse matrix to "delete" something. but watchout from which side you multiply

Comment: @Fay Is this everything you know about $A,B,C$ or are there further properties?

Comment: This is known as [*Lyapunov equation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation) in control theory.

Comment: @user1551, thank you for give me the name of this equation, it's hard for me to find it out by describing.

Comment: @flawr B and C are both square. This equation is exactly Lyapunov equation, and the resolution can be found on wikipedia. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $vec(A)$ denote the [vectorization operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_%28mathematics%29), and let $\otimes$ denote the Kronecker product.  We can then rewrite both sides of the equation to get
$$
(I - B \otimes B) \,vec(A) = vec(CC^T)
$$
Assuming invertibility, we have
$$
vec(A) = (I - B \otimes B)^{-1}vec(CC^T)
$$

Comment: You may be able to make this into a smaller system using [half-vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_%28mathematics%29#Half-vectorization) (since $A$ is symmetric), but I'm not sure what doing this to both sides will do to the matrix $I - B \otimes B$

Comment: Note that $I - B \otimes B$ is invertible if and only if $B$ is square and no two (not necessarily distinct) eigenvalues $\lambda, \mu$ of $B$ satisfy $\lambda \mu = 1$.

Comment: B and C are all square, thank you for your answer. I have already verified the solution according to your result (the same as we can find of Lyapunov equation), it works well!

Answer (score 2):

If $B$ is small, say $\|B\| < 1$ where $\|\cdot\|$ stands for any [matrix norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm), then $A$ has a solution in the form of a converging series
$$A = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty B^n CC^T (B^T)^n$$
Depends on the form of $B$, you may simplify this further.

If $B$ is not small, the system need not have any solution. 
e.g, when $B$ is an orthogonal matrix, 
$$\text{Tr}(A - BAB^T) = \text{Tr}(A- B^TBA) = 0$$
If $\text{Tr}(CC^T) \ne 0$, there are no solution for your equation.